# Delete single element in dynamic array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm making an array of strings, with 100 elements. I created the array in my .h file:

```
const int N = 100;

typedef struct {
int size = 0;
string *list = new string[N];
} tStringList;
```

Then in my .cpp file, I implement the functions `insert`, `search`, `remove` and `print` for the array. But I don't know how to delete the element at the position `pos` of the array in the function `remove`. I tried this but it gives me error:

```
void remove(tStringList & stringList, int pos){

delete stringList.list[pos];
stringList.size--;
}
```

How do I delete a single element in a dynamic array?

Comment: this is not possible. new and delete in C++ ist not recommendet, use containers like std::vector.

Comment: You need to move the elements from `pos + 1` till `N` to one previous position in the array.

Comment: I picked one of the many duplicates at random. Also see [this list](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=delete+element+array+c%2B%2B+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not to delete the element at pos, you should only move all elements after pos back with something like this:

```
void remove(tStringList & stringList, int pos){
    if(pos < stringList.size && pos >= 0){
        for(int i = pos; i < stringList.size - 1; i++){
            stringList.list[i] = stringList.list[i+1];
        }
        stringList.size--;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the answer with size and pos check.